# JavaCV cvCopy() to add sticker on Image (IplImage)

Tags: android, javacv

I am coping a small overlay image to another image, the small overlay is with transparent background, but after merge, i find the overlay background is black. The code is like this:

```
opencv_core.cvSetImageROI(bgImage, opencv_core.cvRect(left, top, width, height));
opencv_core.cvCopy(overlayImage, bgImage);
opencv_core.cvResetImageROI(bgImage);
```

So javacv not support PNG?